# lodash set Object - Not able to create child object with an integer as key

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, lodash

I'm facing issues setting an object using **Lodash** **set** like this,

```
{
    '288452':  { 
        '57': 'value1',
        '69': 'value2',
        '01': 'value3'
    }
}
```

Below is the code I tried,

```
const _ = require from('lodash');

const obj = {};
_.set(obj, ['288452', '57'], 'value1');
// similarly for other values
```

But this creates an array of size 57 as the value for '288452'.

Am I missing anything? Is this a bug?

Thanks,
Sudheesh CM

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `_setWith` in your case because you have numeric keys

```js
const obj = {};
let a="288452",b="57";
_.setWith(obj, '['+a+']['+b+']', 'value1', Object);
console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How do we do it if both of them are variables?
lodash.setWith(itemsHash, [item.ITM_CD][colorCode], null, Object);
The path for the object.

Should that be a string?? - var path = `[${item.ITM_CD}][${colorCode}]`;
lodash.setWith(itemsHash, path, null, Object);

Comment: @sudheeshcm Updated

Comment: Ok. Let me try that.

Comment: @sudheeshcm No problem. For the next time, try to search first on internet. I've never used Loadash before and found the solution after few seconds of internet searchs

Answer (score 0):

Try with this syntax `_.set(x, '288452.57', 'foo');`.